# How can I pass arguments from perl script to Hive script in Oozie

Tags: hadoop, hive, oozie, hue

I have two files 
1. script file (perl or bash script), which generate 'where' clause dynamically(Ex. date for which data is requried.). 
2. Hive script which consume those date as a arguments. and produced the dataset.

I know that using "day>=${fromdate}" hive script will accept argement from outer world.
My question: How can I pass those arguments to Hive script from another script, in Oozie workflow.

I am  using Hue for designing Oozie workflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *When everything else has failed, read the documentation...*

Look into the `<capture_output/>` flag for your Shell Action #1, how to format your key/value results on StdOut, and how to retrieve the values (by key) in the next Action.